# Guaranteed convergence for Gauss-Seidel by substituting $x = A^T y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, numerical-linear-algebra

[Gauss-Seidel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) iteration is only guaranteed to converge if $A$ is symmetric and positive definite. Say I want to solve $Ax=b$ where $A$ is some arbitrary matrix of full row rank. Gauss-Seidel may converge by chance, if I'm lucky, assuming that $A$ is even a square matrix. However, say I instead use Gauss-Seidel to solve $My=b$ with $M = A A^T$. $M$ is symmetric, $(A A^T)^T = A A^T$, and positive definite because $A$ has full row rank, so I am guaranteed convergence.

But $x = A^T y$ is a solution to the original system.

So do I essentially get to apply Gauss-Seidel to solve *any* system of linear equations by using this trick?

I also noticed that Gauss-Seidel with this trick is equivalent to [Kaczmarz method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaczmarz_method). Kinda neat.

Answer (score 0):

Only few details: $$Ax=b \Rightarrow A^TAx =A^T b \Rightarrow Mx = A^Tb = \tilde b$$ with $M$ being [positive definite since it can be decomposed into the product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Decomposition) $A^TA$ of invertible matrices $A$.